# How to distribute on string type data in Python?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a dataset like this:

```
EmployeeID    BenefitsType    Status    YearsInJob   Tenure
000001          M              A            3.1        3-
000002          O              T            2.9        2-3
000003          N              A            5.1        3- 
000004          B              A            0.9        0-1
```

I would like to plot the data as the Tenure distribution based on different categories. For example:

```
sns.distplot(wk[(wk.Benefits=="M")&(wk.Status=="A")]['Tenure'],color = "blue", bins=20)
sns.distplot(wk[(wk.Benefits=="M")&(wk.Status=="T")]['Tenure'],color = "red", bins=20)
```

But the above codes cannot distribute on the String type data like Tenure. Even the plot could give the bar's image (even not in good order), it cannot give the distribution line, which turns out to be a ValueError: could not convert string to float: '60-'
 [image]

If I am going to use exact month data, then the numbers on X-axis would be super crowded. 
[image]

Is there a better way to interpret it?